# how to install libxml2 in ubuntu 15.10

Tags: libraries

I am having Ubuntu 15.10 Desktop. I want to install libxml2. So any one tell me how i can install it. What i need to do to install libxml2 in my laptop. I am almost new to Linux, using it at least from 5-6 months.

Answer (score 47):

There's a [`libxml2` package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libxml2) for that. You can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2
```

If you want to compile software from source based on libxml2 you need the development files:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
```

Comment: Tonight I had to use `sudo apt install libxml2-utils` because of this error: `XMLLINT not set and xmllint not found in path; skipping xml preprocessing.`. Only mentioning in case it helps someone someday.

Comment: @DhirenHamal: If you have a different solution, please write your own answer. [`libxml++2.6-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libxml++2.6-dev) is a different piece of software than [`libxml2-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libxml2-dev) although the former depends on the latter and will thus imply its installation.

Answer (score 6):

This tutorial will tell you exactly how to do it: https://geeksww.com/tutorials/libraries/libxml/installation/installing_libxml_on_ubuntu_linux.php

In summary, the steps are just the same as any other software installation:

1. Locate where you can get the latest version of the software. (From google, libxml2 webpage is here: http://www.xmlsoft.org/downloads.html. From there, you can find the ftp location where you can download the software. Notice the latest version available).
2. Download that latest version's .tar.gz file using wget, and extract it using tar command.
3. Compile and install the software by typing these terminal commands from within the extracted folder:

   ```
   ./configure
    make
    sudo make install
   ```

Update: Another way to do it, per the hint from David Foerster's answer, is to simply use apt-get to install the package for you rather than compiling and installing it yourself. The package you want here is probably either libxml2 or libxml2-dev. You can search for the package you want by typing

```
  apt-cache search libxml2
```

Install the package using the typical apt-get method:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Kevin Bowen. I've edited my answer to include more details. Please don't delete my answer lol--I am honestly trying to help the OP here..

Comment: Thanks for returning and improving your answer. It's appreciated. Welcome to AU!

Answer (score 1):

Find the name of the package you want to install with `dpkg -l libxml\*`. On my system (YMMV) it shows 36 packages related to `libxml`. `sudo apt-get install` the packages you like.